# Routing in express does not behave as I expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I want to have all my express routing in a separate file from the main one. However, for some reason I get an error describing my paths are in the wrong order. Why is this?

My thought process was this: I thought `var routes = require('./routes/index.js);` would call upon the file `index.js` in the folder `routes`. Within `index.js`, the file would `get` the server and `respond` by sending the file `tester.hbs` within `views` expressed by `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/tester.hbs');`. Then `router` gets exported by `module.exports`. Same logic with css file. Lastly, the file `index.js` gets called upon in `server.js` through `app.use('/',routes);`. However, what appears to be happening to me is that server looks into the `routes` file but instead of responding with `index.js` it goes "further" into the `routes` file to find `views/tester`. I do not know why this is.

file directory:

```
new
|
node_modules
public---tester.css
views---tester.hbs
routes---index.js
server.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\new\routes\views\tester.hbs'
```

server.js:

```
//Modules
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express');
var app = app();
var path = require('path');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
//Routes
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index.js');
//Server
var hostname = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 8000;

//Static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname +'views')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname +'public')));
app.use('/',routes);


//View engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'tester', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//Live server
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
    res.end('Still in server.js');
});

app.listen(8000);

module.exports = app;
```

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var app = require('express')();

router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/tester.html');

});
router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/tester.css');
});


module.exports = router;
```

I expect that the server looks into `routes/index.js` through `var routes = require('./routes/index.js');` and `app.use('/',routes);` and from there `index.js` would call upon `views/tester.hbs`, though this is not the case.

Comment: i think it should be var routes = require('../routes/index.js');

Comment: Terminal responds with ```Error: Cannot find module '../routes/index.js'``` @metal

Comment: sorry, how about in your routes.js, change this /views/tester.html to ../views/tester.html

Comment: Terminal responds with ```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\new\routes..\views\tester.hbs```. Also, could you explain what ```../``` does? @metal

Comment: if you want to access a directory outside your working directory, you will use ../

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a file which is in the path __dirname + views/tester.html. 
[__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) gives you the path for the current file, which is your routes folder, then you are saying to get tester.html inside views folder, but routes doesn't contain any folder called views. So, after __dirname you need to go one level back and then go to views/tester.hbs.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../views/tester.hbs"));
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../public/tester.css"));
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Writing all the routes in a single file is a bad approach. The best way to do routing is in separate files. It will be like `routes/routingfiles`.And your index routing file will be look like this.

```
const glob = require('glob');

const routes = [];
glob.sync( './server/routes/**/*.js' ).forEach( function( file ) {
    if(!(file.includes("index"))){
        routes.push(file.replace('/server',''));
    }
  });

module.exports = routes;
```

Then in app.js you need to do this.

```
routes.forEach(function(route) {
    let controller = require(route);
    app.use("/", controller);
});
```

That's the proper way of routing in separate files. If you need more help you can use this [Node Project Git Repo](https://github.com/abdulhaqshah/be-prepared-app-bk).